# Can't process the form in the controller - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I just started using symfony and I'm trying to make a simple prime number checker. The controller doesn't seem to properly work though, because even though I see the form, after I input the number nothing happens ( A text should appear saying if the number is prime or not )

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\calculator;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/prime")
     */
    public function ListAction()
    {


        return $this->render('todo/index.html.twig');
    }
    public function doitAction(Request $request)
    {


        $data = $form->getData();
        return calculator::checknumber($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question or add some code.

Comment: where does `$form` come? is it populated with the `Request`? did you read [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is missing so much that I'm not sure if you removed it on purpose or it's really this empty.

Please do form examples from documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

main part you are missing is

```
if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();

    // do something, render template etc
}
```